# Ruby on Rails form_remote_tag missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using `form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "home", :action => "search"}, :update => "mydiv")`.  When I click submit on the form "mydiv" is populated with the error "Template is missing.  Missing template home/search.erb in view path app/views".  I've tried multiple `render` options in `def search`, but they all result in the same error.

It looks like the search method is trying to use it's default render even though I'm specifying what I want.

I've tried:
`render 'index'`
`render :text => 'Return this from my method!'`

Is my url incorrect? Is it not submitting back to my home controller's search method?

Comment: Could you post the source of the search action in the home controller, and the route that defines the search action?

Comment: Adding `render :layout => false` to my search method was the culprit. I thought that would be necessary since I just wanted to update part of the page.  

I also changed my render statement in "search" to `render :partial => 'partial_containing_mydiv'`.

The new problem is that nothing is rendered, but my code is being executed.  I'll create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
render :action => 'index'
```

this will use "index.rhtml" or "index.html.erb".

Comment: I believe his use of `render 'index'` is the same as `render :action => 'index'`... I think...

Comment: Add this in my search method?  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the submit is hitting the search method at all.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain why it said search.erb is not found, lets take create action for a some model, if there is some error in my create action they it will throw missing template create.html.erb file, since you have some error in your create action rails will try to render the create.html.erb in the page. Hope I explained it clearly.

In an ajax action you can't use redirect_to or render options directly.
try using this in your search action

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html "ur_div_id","partial"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The `form_remote_tag` needs prototype to function. Make sure you are including the `:defaults` for your javascript libraries namely prototype.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Comment: it's included in my default layout file, which I've set `render :layout => false` in the search method.  If I leave the layout then "mydiv" is populated with the whole page.

Comment: If this were the solution he would not be getting missing template errors